# How to set distinct attributes on getters and setters in F#?

Tags: f#

This seems to work fine in C#:

```
class A : System.Attribute { public A() {} }

public class B
{
    public int X
    {
        [A] get { return 1; }
        [A] set { }
    }
}
```

But in F#, as I try to set attributes on property getters and setters, I cannot get around a syntax error:

```
type A() = inherit System.Attribute()

type B = 
    member this.X 
        with [<A>] get () = 1
        and  [<A>] set (x : int) = ()
```

Is there a way to do it?

My goal is to set distinct attributes on the getters and setters.

Comment: This now appears to work as expected, though I'm not sure when it was fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MSDN-documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483467(VS.100).aspx) suggest the following:

```
type A() = inherit System.Attribute()

type B =     
    [<A>]
    member this.X with get () = 1
    [<A>]
    member this.X with set (x : int) = ()
```

... but according to [.Net Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) it doesn't seem to produce the expected IL. Looks like a bug to me.

*Edit: Or a bug in [.Net Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)...*

*Edit 2: Bug report submitted to fsbugs@microsoft.com*

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I can't seem to be able to retrieve the setter attribute by reflection. I am contacting fsbugs@...

Comment: This still does not appear to work (despite the documentation), while @t0yv0's initial attempt now does work.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, the reply from the F# team was:

> Right now (and also in the upcoming
>   Beta2), attributes targeting property
>   getters and setters specifically are
>   not supported.